# Python subprocess argument with quotes

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo command-line utility from python.
It accepts arguments like this.

****Simple Usage: ****

```
# verbose all info
MediaInfo.exe test.mp4
```

**Template Usage:**

```
# verbose selected info from csv    
MediaInfo.exe --inform="file://D:\path\to\csv\template.csv" test.mp4
```

I am trying to run it with Template argument.I can use above command successfully from CMD.It is working and i can see my selected output fine from Dos window.

But when I try to run it from python , it outputs all info ignoring CSV which I give as argument.
Can anyone explain why ? It is because of quotes ?

**NOTE:** If path to csv not correct/invalid csv, MediaInfo outputs all info which is happening here exactly.

```
#App variable is full path to MediaInfo.exe
#filename variable is full path to media file

proc  =  subprocess.Popen([App ,'--inform="file://D:\path\to\csv\template.csv"',filename],shell=True,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
return_code = proc.wait()
for line in proc.stdout:
    print line
```

Comment: You may safely use / instead of \ on Windows

Comment: doesnot work with file://D:/path/to/ also.I tried file://D:\\path\\to also, not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you could pass the command as string i.e., as is:

```
from subprocess import check_output

cmd = r'MediaInfo.exe --inform="file://D:\path\to\csv\template.csv" test.mp4'
out = check_output(cmd)
```

Notice: `r''` -- the raw-string literal is used to avoid interpreting `'\t'`  as a single tab character instead of `r'\t'` two characters (backslash and `t`).

Unrelated: if you have specified `stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE` then you should read *both* streams *concurrently* and *before* `p.wait()` is called otherwise a deadlock is possible if the command generates enough output.

---

If the passing of the command as a string works then your could try a list argument:

```
from subprocess import check_output
from urllib import pathname2url

cmd = [app, '--inform']
cmd += ['file:' + pathname2url(r'D:\path\to\csv\template.csv')]
cmd += [filename]
out = check_output(cmd)
```

---

> Also can u write a example for p.wait() deadlock u mentioned.

It is easy. Just produce large output in the child process:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

#XXX DO NOT USE, IT DEADLOCKS
p = Popen([sys.executable, "-c", "print('.' * (1 << 23))"], stdout=PIPE)
p.wait() # <-- this never returns unless the pipe buffer is larger than (1<<23)
assert 0 # unreachable
```

Comment: Ok. This works but can you explain how can i fix this using subprocess command which i posted , for understanding ? Also can u write a example for p.wait() deadlock u mentioned.I couldnt get your point.

Comment: @django: `check_output()` is *the way* to fix your command. I've added code example that demonstrates the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

If you `print` your arguments, you might see what is going wrong:

```
>>> print '--inform="file://D:\path\to\csv\template.csv"'
--inform="file://D:\path    o\csv   emplate.csv"
```

The problem is `\` denotes special characters. If you use the "r" literal in front of your string, these special characters are not escaped:

```
>>> print r'--inform="file://D:\path\to\csv\template.csv"'
--inform="file://D:\path\to\csv\template.csv"
```

Comment: putting r before '--inform= also doesnot help.Same full output :(

Comment: is there a way to print what subprocess is actually running command in full with arguments ?